# "Rely" vs. "Relies" usage

Tags: grammar

> 1. The subjective nature of these tests **rely** on human expertise to assess the patient correctly
> 2. The subjective nature of these tests **relies** on human expertise to assess the patient correctly

Which is correct to say, and why?

Comment: Neither makes sense, though the first is also ungrammatical.

Comment: In what way does it not make sense? I'm curious if it could be interpreted in the wrong way?

Comment: Actually, I see what you mean. "These tests are subjective in nature and rely on human expertise to assess the patient correctly" is more clear.

Comment: It's a more precise restatement: "These tests are subjective in nature, relying as they do on human expertise to assess the patient correctly"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is "the subjective ***nature*** (of these tests)". Therefore "rely" is inflected in agreement with "nature", which is singular.

Thus the only correct one is

> The subjective nature of these tests relies on human expertise to assess the patient correctly

Comment: I like your word *concruence*!

Comment: *Cunjugated* also has a certain *je ne sais quoi*.

Comment: Happy? The "u" was obviously a mere blooper and since "Concruence" is used in this context in German, I couldn't know that, for whichever reason, this isn't the case in English. Hvor rart af dig at rette mig.

Comment: This made me more confused than previously. If the subject determine which one is correct depending on plural/singular how come these contradict each other: 'He relies on her', 'I rely on her', 'you rely on her', 'our car relies on us'. Is there an exception to I/you?